# SVN Conflicts a new resource

Tags: eclipse, svn, conflict, tigris

I am completely at loss with this conflict in SVN with Eclipse. I am trying to merger a range revisions from branch. A brand new folder is being added and couple of xhtml files inside. What I am perplexed is, merge info says there is a conflict on only one file inside this folder. Remember that whole folder is getting added. Can someone explain what is going on ?

Comment: maybe you are adding a folder that was already added to the server in the meantime

Comment: Maybe this file (inducing conflict) has been added/removed/re-added or moved in the branch... it might bring issues during merge.

Comment: @Petr Kozelka, no folder was never added before this. Laurent, that sheds some light, I will look to see if the team did that. Thank you for your answers.